# How to prevent selection of new added element on top of JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, multipleselection

I have a JTable that contains one row. I'am using multiple selection interval as a selection mode, besides a new row will be inserted on top of the table after 5 seconds from execution. My problem is: When I run the code and select the first row, after 5 seconds a new row is added (this is OK) but I got two selected rows which I do not want because I need to preserve the old selection,that means after adding the new row only the second row is selected. How to resolve this problem using multiple selection interval mode? Here is my code:

```
   public static void main(String args[]) {
    Object[][] rowData = { { "Hello", "World" }, { "By By", "World" } };
    Object[] columnNames = { "A", "B" };
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Selecting JTable");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    final DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(rowData,columnNames);

    JTable jtable = new JTable(model);
    jtable.setSelectionMode(
            ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
    JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(jtable);
    frame.add(scrollPane1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(640, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(6000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    model.insertRow(0, rowData[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `removeRowSelectionInterval` method right after you insert the row.

Something like:

```
int newRowIndex = 0;
model.insertRow(newRowIndex, rowData[0]);
jtable.removeRowSelectionInterval(newRowIndex, newRowIndex);
```